# Creating a TypeORM entity based on another domain-level class without decorators

Tags: node.js, typescript, orm, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I would like to separate between domain-level, pure business logic entities - and the TypeORM / any other framework bindings.

For example, right now an Address looks like this in order to bind it with TypeORM:

```
@Entity()
export class Address {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  streetAddress1: string;
}
```

I would rather have a pure data class such as

```
export class Address {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  streetAddress1: string;
}
```

And define the TypeORM binding from another place, to separate concerns and not have my core business logic know anything about TypeORM (Or any other framework I might migrate to).

How would you approach this in a clean way, without creating a duplicate entity class just for TypeORM?
Any clever way to use the TypeScript type system to extend the existing pure entity class and decorate it for TypeORM DB binding?

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to create a type from your TypeORM model, I've renamed it `AddressEntity`:

```js
@Entity()
export class AddressEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  streetAddress1: string;
}

...

type Address = typeof AddressEntity

const address: Address = {
   // ... typescript requires that you define these fields
}
```

Comment: The problem here is that in this way, my domain layer depends on how stuff gets defined in TypeORM (a class with decorated fields).
What would happen when I switch to a different framework, which defines DB entities differently?
I'm giving you an upvote anyway, since this is going in the right direction.